# Print string if between "-" and "-"

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which has multiple strings between '-', and i'm trying to print every string that is between '-'

I have tried this code but, it's skipping values.

```
import re

text=   """
        -text1-text2-text3
        -text4-
        """

result = re.findall(r'-(.*?)-', text)
print(result,end="")
```

I'm trying to get the result to come up like this:

['text1','text2','text3'],'text4']

but instead my code is skipping values and giving me this:

['text1','text4']

Comment: Glad [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56657274/3832970) worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
-\s*(.*?)(?=\s*-)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/meq4zu/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=-%5Cs*(.*%3F)(%3F%3D%5Cs*-)):

[image]

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EoRBM3):

```
import re
text=   """
        -text1-text2-text3
        -text4-
        """
result = re.findall(r'-\s*(.*?)(?=\s*-)', text)
print(result) # => ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']
```

If you need to match across lines, add the `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` flag to `re.findall`.

**Regex details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?=\s*-)` - a  positive lookahead that requires 0+ whitespaces and then `-` immediately to the right of the current location

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple regex  `r'(?<=-)[^-]*(?=-)'`

```
>>> import re
>>> text=   """
...         -text1-text2-text3
...         -text4-
...         """
>>> print ([x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'(?<=-)[^-]*(?=-)', text)])
['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']
```